# Zero locus of maximal ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A = k[x_{1}, . . . , x_{n}]$, where k is an algebraically closed field. If $M_{1}, . . . , M_{r}$ are maximal ideals of A, where $M_{i}\neq M_{j}$ if $i\neq j$, and $s_{1}, . . . , s_{r}$ are positive integers, prove that $V(M^{s1}_{1} ∩ · · · ∩ M^{sr}_{r})$ is the union of r distinct points of $A^{n}_{k}$
.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about the problem?

Comment: In the previous part I had to prove that if I have two ideals and their sum equals the whole ring, then their intersection equals their product, so I guess I have to use that

Comment: Do you know that $V_(A \cap B) = V(A) \cup C(B)$?

Comment: Yes, but what happens with the exponents then?

Comment: Oh don't worry, I got it, I wasn't using that they are maximal ideals